# how to check log in mysql

Tags: mysql

How would i monitor a MySQL to detect SELECTs which are running slowly?  Having identified a poorly performing SELECT, how would i analyse it with a view to improving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL keeps a 'slow query log' which will provide you with information about slow running queries.

I think it's enabled by default, and its location is set in your MySQL .ini file.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) for more information on the slow query log.

You can use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to get information about how MySQL is executing your queries - just put `EXPLAIN` before your query. There is a good article [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm) on how to interpret the results.

Answer (score 2):

You would enable [slow query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) logging, e.g. add this to your `my.cnf`  under the `[mysqld]` section

```
set-variable=slow_query_log=on
set-variable=long_query_time=20
```

This will log all queries taking 20 seconds or more to a "hostname"-slow.log, e.g. /var/lib/mysql/localhost-slow.log

You'd then inspect those queries, and at least run [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on them, and figure out what makes it slow, e.g. add indexes, rewrite the SQL etc. - though optimizing queries is a whole other book.